# Lubuntu 12.04: Cannot transfer files from the laptop to the Nexus 7

Tags: lubuntu, nexus-7

I just recently got myself a Nexus 7 and I want to load it up with some apps that I've downloaded on the laptop. The problem is that I can't get the Nexus 7 to mount on the laptop. I've tried different ports but they all lead to the same result. I've even tried connecting it as a camera, but then I wouldn't be able to access the whole device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same problem a while a go. The solution I found was not to use the USB cable at all. Although you can eventually get the MTP configuration to sort of work, it remains buggy.

In the end I chose to transfer files over my local WIFI. Assuming you have both your laptop and your tablet connected to the same wireless network, all you need to do really is to share one or more folders on your laptop (right click, sharing options). Once that is done you need a file manager tool on your Nexus. I use the free version of File Manager HD (from Google Play). In this you select "Network" from the top row of options and enter the connection details. To avoid issues with server paths, using the IP adress of your laptop. Don't forget to enter username and password, it is saved in the connection info so you only have to do it once. Important to realize is that each shared folder requires a separate entry.

Hope this works for you